# How to generate a right angle Fibonacci Series pyramid in Java?

Tags: java, for-loop, logic, fibonacci

**I want to generate an output like this :-**

0

0 1

0 1 1

0 1 1 2

0 1 1 2 3

0 1 1 2  3 5

However, i am trying in this way to achieve , but some piece of logic is missing which i am unable to decipher.

**Here's what i am trying :-**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Fibonacci

{

public static void main(String arr[])

{

System.out.println("Enter a no.");

Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);

int num=input.nextInt();

int x=0,y=1;

for(int i=0;i<=num;i++)

{

for(int j=0;j<i;j++)

{

System.out.print(j);

}

System.out.println("");

}

}

}
```

And it generates the output like this *(consider num=6)*

0

0 1

0 1 2

0 1 2 3

0 1 2 3 4

0 1 2 3 4 5

What logic is required to get the desired output ? Would be thankful if anyone can explain me this :)

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: You literally just print out the current iteration. There is no fibonacci involved... What do you even expect?

Comment: You are printing out variable "j", and only increment it each time in your new for loop.. you're not actually calculating the Fibonacci sequence in your code

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number I'm not sure why you didn't just google this. Theres answers literally everywhere for this type of question.

Comment: I googled this but i was unable to apply this in my code. I even tried it differently but couldn't get through

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First two numbers 0 and 1 are given , no need to caculate .
2. Use a `String` to save previous line string .
3. Caculate next numbers , add it into your previous line string .

Here is an example :

```
int x = 0 , y = 1;

int num = 6;

System.out.println("0");
System.out.println("0 1");

String str = "0 1";

for(int i = 2 ; i < num ; i ++){
    int amt = x + y ;

    x = y;
    y = amt;

    str += " " + amt;

    System.out.println(str);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change logic of inner loop like this by adding two previous number to current number and swap them like this.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Fibonacci

{

    public static void main(String arr[])

    {

        int x = 0, y = 0, c = 0;

        System.out.println("Enter a no.");

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int num = input.nextInt();

        for (int count = 0; count < num; count++) {

            System.out.print(0);
            x = 0;
            y = 1;
            c = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++) {

                c = x + y;

                y = x;
                x = c;

                System.out.print(" " + c);
            }
            System.out.println();

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In a Fibonacci series only the first two numbers are provided which are 0 and 1. The next number of the series are calculated by adding the last two numbers. The series is limited by the user by providing the number of integers it wants in the series.

**Logic**: The logic behind creating a Fibonacci series is to add the two integers and save them in a new variable `z = x+y` and then replace the first integer value by the second integer and second integer value by their sum to move one step ahead in the series `x=y` adn `y=z`.

In your problem you want the series to be printed in a right angled triangle so you need to save the series that is already printed in a string

```
int n = 10;
System.out.println("0\n");
System.out.println("0 1\n");
int x = 0, y=1;
int i=2, z=0;
String str = "0 1";
while(i!=10)
{
    z = x+y;
    str += " " + z;
    x=y;
    y=z;
    i++;
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

Hope this helps